# PHP FOR loop stops after 2 loops, exit status 139

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scraperwiki

I'm building a scraper with Scraper Wiki, here: https://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/fashfinder/edit/#

Without boring you with too many details, I load up about 120 links into an array, $allLinks. Then, at the bottom of the page, I call a FOR loop on the array as follows:

```
for ($i = 0; $i<count($allLinks); $i++){
   getInfo($allLinks[$i]);
};
```

getInfo() is a function that gets product information from the supplied links. The function works fine for $i = 0 and $i = 1. Then, when $i = 2 something breaks - the source is loaded in the scraper and the whole thing stops. No errors but it says "Exit Status 139".

I tried reversing the $allLinks array with `$allLinks = array_reverse($allLinks);` but the exact same thing occurred - it scraped 2 pages, got to the 3rd then suddenly stopped.

Any ideas on what's going wrong here? Can't find much info on what "EXIT STATUS 139" means, especially regarding scraperwiki!

Comment: Do a barrell roll xD....put some info on the var_dump or print_r on the $allLinks var please

Comment: @RobertRozas Here ya go http://pastebin.com/LNMtds2Z pretty much the correct output - it's grabbing 122 links. The problem is with the FOR loop but no idea what.

Comment: @RobertRozas Even when I set ` for ($i = 0; $i<100; $i++){` i get the error, looks like a problem on scraperwiki's end?

Comment: @RobertRozas The issue is most likely in the getInfo function. Comment it out and just put a `echo 'test';` or something to see it work.

Comment: @sachleen has a good idea.

Comment: I think the same based in the pastebin...you should write your getInfo function.

Comment: and I don´t recommend you use count($allLinks) as your validator... it will count the entire array each time. It would be better to save the count on a var before the for... or use the foreach

Comment: @RobertRozas The getInfo function is in the original link in the OP. Here's a pastebin of the function on its own though http://pastebin.com/XGyVdmAu

Answer (score 0):

May be trying this:

```
foreach ($arrayLinks as $key => $value) {
  getInfo($value);
}
```

PS: Your var_dump of the array looks fine, maybe ut's a issue with your getInfo function.

Saludos ;)

Comment: the foreach will not solve the problem, but I agree it will be more efficient than the current for.

Comment: Thats right....but like i said....i think that the problem may exist in the getInfo() function.

Comment: @RobertRozas Here is the getInfo() function: http://pastebin.com/XGyVdmAu And here is the code in its entirety: http://pastebin.com/SZ8XFCaF

Comment: I recently found this information: exit code 139 is signal 139-128=11, segmentation fault. This could be a null pointer dereference or heap corruption. It's undeniably a bug, but the cause could be pretty much anything.